# What is the easiest example of a finitely presented group which is not residually finite?

Tags: group-theory

What is an easy example of a finitely presented group which is not [residually finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group)?

To be clear, part of the question is: how do we see that it isn't?

Comment: The Baumslag–Solitar group B(2,3) is a classical example, it has an incredibly simple presentation, and showing it is not hopfian (and therefore non-residually finite)  is done using the basic tools of combinatorial group theory... What does *easy* mean, exactly?

Comment: Terry Tao's blogpost http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/10/06/finite-subsets-of-groups-with-no-finite-models/ gives a fairly simple example.

Comment: Further to MarianoSuárez-Alvarez's comment, there is a classification of Baumslag-Solitar groups with respect to whether they are Hopfian, residually finite, or neither. See my post here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79852/does-g-cong-g-h-imply-that-h-is-trivial/79907#79907

Comment: Also, there is a recent paper (2007) by, among others, the Baumslag of Baumslag-Solitar fame, called "Reflections on the residual finiteness of one-relator groups". In this paper the authors prove that if $r$ and $w$ are non-commuting words in the free group $F(a, b, \ldots)$ then the group $\langle a, b, \ldots ; r^{r^w}=r^2\rangle$ is not residually finite. Which is pretty.