# Are isomorphic orders in a quadratic field always equal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$ be a quadratic field. Let $O_j = \Bbb Z + f_j O_K$ be two orders in $O_K$.

Assume that $O_1 \cong O_2$ as rings. Does it follow that $O_1 = O_2$ (i.e. their conductors are the same)?

We know that $f_j = [O_K : O_j]$, but isomorphic subgroups don't need to have the same index in general (cf [Isomorphic subgroups, finite index, infinite index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193525/isomorphic-subgroups-finite-index-infinite-index)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true. In general, if $R$ is an integral domain with fraction field $K$, the index of $R$ in its integral closure $R^0$ in $K$ is an isomorphism invariant of $R$.

Comment: This is a cool fact. Would you have a hint about the proof?

Comment: I was thinking that an isomorphism $R \to R'$ extends (via $\otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Q$) to a $\Bbb Q$-algebra (?) morphism $K \to K$, but why would it leave $R$ invariant? Or how to use the fact $\mathrm{char}(R) = 0$ ?

Comment: @Alphonse the field of fractions is just the set of symbols $r/s$ and an isomorphims $\phi: R \to R'$ extends to an isomorphism from $K$ to $K'$ taking $r/s$ to $\phi(r)/\phi(s)$. This isomorphism must take the integral closure of $R$ in $K$ to the integral closure of $R'$ in $K'$ (the latter is just the set of roots in $K'$ of monic polynomials with coefficients in $R'$; pull the polynomials back along $\phi$.)

Comment: (also, sorry, should have said "integral domain" and not "ring of characteristic zero," have now edited answer!)