# Homomorphism and isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to find an example of a group epimorphism $f:G\to G$ which is not an isomorphism.

I understand that $G$ should an infinite group.

Comment: Such a group is called non-Hopfian. See [this old question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79852/does-g-cong-g-h-imply-that-h-is-trivial/) for examples.

Comment: You need a non-hopfian group, which are not that easy to spot and are rather nasty in a way: try $$BS(2,3):=\langle\;a,b\;;\;b^{-1}a^2b=a^3\;\rangle$$ and the map $\;a\mapsto a^2\;,\;b\mapsto b\;$

Comment: @user1729: I am so sorry for my self. This is the second duplicate question I have seen.

Comment: (It is interesting to note that Don Antonio's group is finitely presented, but neither of the two in the answers here are.)

Comment: Indeed @user1729...and as such it *must* be non-residually finite since it is non-hopfian.

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed! Have you ever read Higman's paper which gives a 3-generator, 2-relator example? It is actually really easy to see that it is non-Hopfian - easier than Baumslag-Solitar's example. I feel that this is much more pleasing than the BS-example because I can see where it comes from... Take $A\leq H$ and suppose there exists an automorphism $\phi$ of $H$ such that $A\phi=B\lneq A$. Then take $G_A=H_1\ast_{A_1=A_2}H_2$ (H_i=H, etc.). This is isomorphic to $G_B=H_1\ast_{B_1=B_2}H_2$, but the natural map $G_B\rightarrow G_A$ got by adding in the rest of $A$ has non-trivial kernel.

Comment: (@DonAntonio Also, in the (specific) example Higman gives, the non-injective endomorphism an a Nielsen transformation. I find this incredibly disturbing. Although...when I think about it, this is probably true always - every automorphism of a group can be viewed as a Nielsen transformation over some generating set, so I presume the same holds even if we relax the injectivity. I think I might need to lie down now.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider infinite direct sums (of copies of a given group)...

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ is prime and let the group $G=\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})=\{\frac{a}{p^k}+\mathbb Z\mid (a,p)=1,k\in\mathbb N\}$. I hope you know this fact that for any subgroup $H$ of the group above; $G/H\cong G$. Now I am thinking of the natural epimorphism $\pi: G\to G$.

Comment: but domain and codomain should be same

Comment: @SucharitaDeb: They are the same. In fact, group $G$ is abelian and maybe you wanted the group  to be non-abelian.

Comment: Well done, @Babak...but in the last line I think you may have meant $\;\pi :G\to G\;$ +1

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes I have, Don.

Comment: Babak gives here what is perhaps the easiest, or maybe the best well-known, example of non-hopfian group: the Prüfer $\;p-$group $\,\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}\;$

Comment: Indeed, DonAntonio is correct! +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider $G = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ under addition and the map sending $a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_n x^n$ to $a_1 + a_2 x +...+ a_n x^{n-1}$. This is clearly an epimorphism yet isn't injective.

Also for a contextual example the derivative map on $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Isn't this just a different way of viewing anon's example? (I ask to verify my thinking, not to criticise.)

Comment: Yes...however anon didn't really give an example! Just gave a group which you can construct such a map on.