# Fundamental group of a Cayley graph

Tags: group-theory, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Could someone please indicate the proof of the following fact (I believe strongly, but I am not sure, that this is true). Let $F$ be a free group of finite rank, $N<F$ a normal subgroup and $G=F/N$. Let $X$ be the Cayley graph of $G$. Then $\pi_1(X)$ is isomorphic to $N$.

I can prove the existence of an epimorphism $N\to \pi_1(X)$, but cannot prove that it is injective. (The homomorphism associates to a word in $N$ the class of the loop obtained by lifting the word to $X$.)

Also, I have the following related question: Suppose that $M<N<F$ (proper inclusions), with $F,N$ as above and $M$ normal in $F$. Is it possible that $F/M\simeq F/N$?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: How do you define $\pi_1(X)$ for a graph $X$?

Comment: $\pi_1(X)$ is defined for any topological space. A Cayley graph is a CW complex.

Comment: With respect to your second question, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79852/does-g-cong-g-h-imply-that-h-is-trivial/) and its answers.

Answer (score 5):

The answer for the second question is "Yes": not all groups (even finitely generated) are Hopfian.

For the first question, it is also obviously "Yes": the graph of $F$, which is contractible, covers that of $G$.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Still regarding the first question, I do not understand why it is obvious that $\pi_1(X)\simeq N$ follows from the fact that $F$ covers $X$: $F$ covers the Cayley graph of any group generated by (rank $F$) elements. Perhaps it is obvious to you that the group of deck transformations of $X_F\to X_G$ is isomorphic to $N$? I cannot see this. Could you clarify?

Comment: The Cayley graph of $G$ is the quotient of the Cayley tree of F by the fixed point free (and hence properly discontinuous) action of $N$.  Thus the group of deck transformations is $N$ by standard covering space theory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the fundamental group of a graph is always a free group, so it can not be $F/N$. To get a space with $\pi_1X=F/N$ you will have to fill in 2-cells whose boundaries correspond to elements of $N$.

Comment: See e.g. http://www.math.unl.edu/~mbrittenham2/classwk/990s08/public/seifert.van.kampen.examples.pdf

Comment: The question was not why $\pi_1 X \simeq F/N$. The question was why $\pi_1 X \simeq N$.