# A group is simple if an only if its homomorphic images are the trivial group and $G$ itself (up to isomorphism)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

I need to prove the following:

> Let $G$ be a group.
>   Then it's simple if and only if there is only surjective homomorphism $G \to G'$ for $G' = \{ e \}$ or $G' \cong G$.

Not sure how to approach this problem. So far I only have proved that if $G$ is simple and a homomorphism is surjective, then so is $G'$, but I'm not sure this is relevant.

The question is not a duplicate, since it also asks how to prove ($G$ is simple, $\phi: G \to G'$ is a surjective homomorphism) $\Rightarrow$ ($G' = \{ e \}$ or $G' \cong G$).

Comment: Kernels of group homomorphisms are normal, and normal subgroups are kernels of the associated quotient homomorphism.

Comment: Hint: The kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup.

Comment: This is probably not true as stated (though I don't know a counterexample off the top of my head).  You need to say not just $G'\cong G$ but that in that case the surjective homomorphism in question is an isomorphism.

Comment: @user1729 I don't think it is a duplicate, and I edited to explain why.

Comment: @Jxt921 I disagree: I believe this is a duplicate, because the linked question gives a counter-example to your statement. One direction holds, yes, but you were not asking about one direction but both. I suggest you ask the other direction in a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

This is not true. It holds for finite groups, but not in general.

The issue is that a surjective homomorphism $G\rightarrow G$ need not be an isomorphism. If there exists a non-injective surjective homomorphism $G\rightarrow G$ then $G$ is called non-Hopfian. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79852/does-g-cong-g-h-imply-that-h-is-trivial/79907#79907) for more details and explicit examples (easiest example: $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots$).

The Prüfer group $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]/\mathbb{Z}$ gives a couner-example to your specific question: it is not simple, but all homomorphic images are either isomorphic to itself or are trivial (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768561/sort-of-simple-non-hopfian-groups)).

If you restate your question to be about finite groups instead then it is a relatively straight-forward exercises on the first isomorphism theorem, as the comments and the other answer are getting at.

Comment: I see. However, the question in the link you gave says it hold for finitely generated groups and not just finite.

Comment: And yes, if $\phi: G \to G'$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $G/ \ker \phi \cong G'$, but since $\ker \phi$ is normal and $G$ is simple, then $G' \cong G/ \{ e \} \cong G$ or $G' \cong G/G \cong \{ e \}$.