# Group isomorphic to all its proper quotients, and not simple

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that for any proper normal subgroup $H \subset G$, we have $G/H \cong G$ (of course this isomorphism may not be given by the projection $G \to G/H$). Does it follow that $G$ is a simple group? What can we say about such a group $G$ in general?

Notice that $G/H \cong G$ doesn't imply $H = \{e\}$, for instance $z \mapsto z^2$ is a surjective morphism $\Bbb C^{\times} \to \Bbb  C^{\times}$ of kernel $\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: How does $G/H$ trivial not imply $G=H$? If $g\in G\setminus H$, then $gH\ne 1H$ in $G/H$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  :  thanks, I edited my post.

Comment: You write *non-trivial*, but I think it's *proper* you really mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$The [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) is non-simple, and satisfies your hypothesis.

Given a prime $p$, you realize it as the subgroup of the multiplicative group $\C^{*}$ given by
\begin{equation*}
  G = \Set { z \in \C^{*} : z^{p^{k}} = 1 \ \text{for some $k \ge 0$}}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: @Alphonse the wikipedia reference basically has it all, in particular it lists all the subgroups, which are normal, $G$ being abelian.

Comment: A possibly hard question is whether these are the only examples.

Comment: @YCor You have previously solved your possibly hard question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1985569/10513

Comment: @user1729 oops, thanks very much, I forgot this!

Comment: @YCor, brilliant, thanks!