# Does $ \frac{G}{H}\simeq \frac{G}{K}$ $\Rightarrow$ $H\simeq K$?

Tags: group-theory

> Does $\displaystyle \frac{G}{H}$ $\simeq$ $\displaystyle \frac{G}{K}$ $\Rightarrow$ $H$ $\simeq$ $K$?

I think it's true but I am having trouble demonstrating it.

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroup of a group $G$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{G}{H}$ is isomorphic a $\displaystyle \frac{G}{K}$, then $H$ is isomorphic a $K$.

Comment: I assume you want $H$ and $K$ to be *normal* subgroups?

Comment: No. Hint: Consider a suitable abelian group of order $8$.

Comment: Consider the dihedral group of order $8$ for $G$ and think about its normal subgroups of order $4.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Consider, for example, $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$.

For more extreme examples, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79852/does-g-cong-g-h-imply-that-h-is-trivial). These examples are of infinite groups where $H$ is trivial but $K$ is non-trivial. Such groups are called *non-Hopfian*.