# If $G\simeq K$ and $H\simeq M$ then is it true that $G/ H \simeq K / M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ and $K$ be groups. Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $M$ be a normal subgroup of $K$ such that $H\simeq M$.

Question: is $ G/H \simeq K / M$?

I am fairly certain that this is tru of the groups are finite. For example, if the groups are cyclic, then the quotients are cyclic and by orders of the groups, then quotients would have to be isomorphic.

But what happens when the groups are not finite?

From [Does $\displaystyle \frac{G}{H}$ $\simeq$ $\displaystyle \frac{G}{K}$ $\Rightarrow$ $H$ $\simeq$ $K$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847039/does-displaystyle-fracgh-simeq-displaystyle-fracgk-rightarr) I see that the other direction is not true.

Comment: It fails if $H$ and $K$ are abstractly isomorphic (see, for example, subgroups of free groups), but you do get an isomorphism if you assume that the isomorphism $H \to M$ lifts to an isomorphism $G \to K$.

Comment: ["Duplicate"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/40881/11619) of at least my answer. You be the judge.

Comment: You can also make an intuitive argument why it shouldn't (a priori) be so. Although the notation suggests otherwise, $G/H$ does not only depend on the structure of $G$ and the structure of $H$, but also on the way that $H$ sits in $G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not hold for finite groups either. Let $G=K=\Bbb{Z}_4\oplus\Bbb{Z}_2$, and let $H=\langle (0,1)\rangle$ and $M=\langle(2,0)\rangle$ be the given cyclic subgroups, both of order two. Then
$$
G/H\simeq\Bbb{Z}_4\qquad\text{and}\qquad K/M\simeq\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus\Bbb{Z}_2.
$$
You need to have an isomorphism $f:G\to K$ such that $f(H)=M$ to be sure about the conclusion.

Comment: Fairly sure this is a dup (a standard exercise). Looking...

Comment: Found this [older original](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/40881/11619). Switching my answer to CW.

Comment: Ok, so if $f(H) = M$, then it holds for all groups?

Comment: @JohnDoe:Correct. If you can find such an isomorphism $f$, then the claim follows.

Answer (score 10):

$$\frac{\mathbb Z}{2\mathbb Z}\not\cong \frac{\mathbb Z }{3\mathbb Z},$$

while $\mathbb Z\cong 2\mathbb Z \cong 3\mathbb Z$