# Checking whether a map satisfies being homomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, abstract-algebra

My question might seem silly ,but excuse me for it as I've just started my hand on Ring theory.

My question is :
Like we've in case of group homomorphisms that we can check that a map $\phi :G \rightarrow H$ is in actual a homomorphism by simply checking that it satisfies the relations in the presentation of group $H$ after homomorphism.

*Example*:$\,\,\,\,\,$  consider group homomorphism $\phi :G \rightarrow G$ given by $\phi :g \rightarrow g^2$
If G was the group $\mathbb Z_6\times \mathbb Z_2$=$\langle a,b;a^6=1,b^2=1\rangle$  then you need to verify  that $a^{\text12}=1$ and that $b^4=1$. These  relations all clearly hold, so the map $a\rightarrow a^2,b\rightarrow b^2$ is a homomorphism.

But in case of Ring homomorphism what do we check to see whether a map satisfies being a ring homomorphism? Can anyone explain it to me with an example   .Please help....

Comment: Every commutative ring with $1$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, i.e. has a presentation $R \cong \mathbb{Z}[x_i]/(f_j)$. Then for any ring $S$, giving a ring homomorphism $R \to S$ is equivalent to giving elements $y_i \in S$, one for each $x_i$, such that $f_j(y_i) = 0$ for each $j$. E.g. $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(12,2(x-1),6x,x^2-x)$, so giving a ring map $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \to S$ is equivalent to giving an element $y \in S$ such that $2(y - 1) = 6y = y^2 - y = 12 = 0$ in $S$

Answer (score 2):

A presentation of a group $G$ can (and should be!) thought of as the choice of a free group $F$ (where the generators are our list of symbols), a group homomorphism $\pi:F\to G$, and a list of generators of $\ker{\pi}$.  In this case, we identify $G$ as $F/\ker{\pi}$.

For example, the group $G=\langle a,b;a^6=1,b^2=1\rangle$ is formed by taking $F$ to be the free group on two generators $x$ and $y$, and the generators for $\ker{\pi}$ are $x^6$ and $y^2$ (the point is that these combinations of symbols must both be sent to the identity when we replace $x$ with $a$ and $y$ with $b$).

For rings, the situation is basically identical, but the way free objects look has changed.  A presentation of a ring $R$ is a choice of a *polynomial ring* $F$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.  And now, when we look at the projection $\pi: F\to R$, $\ker{\pi}$ is an *ideal* of $F$.

For example, the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which is the ring "generated" by $i$ with $i^2+1=0$, can be described as the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ by the ideal $(X^2+1)$.

And your observation holds true for rings as well as groups.  If we try to define a function based on the presentations, this is like defining a map between polynomial rings.  This is a morphism of rings precisely when you can, using this map, verify the relations of the target ring using the relations of the source ring.

Comment: NB that spectraa's example $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ also requires the relation $ab = ba$.

Comment: yes @Travis you are correct.that needs to be added...

Comment: @Slade thanks but I haven't yet studied what are free groups....

Comment: @spectraa You know one free group, namely $\mathbb{Z}$, the free group on one generator.  I claim that this plays the same role in describing groups as $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ does in describing rings, namely that each is the simplest way of having one indeterminate, with as few restrictions as possible.  For non-commutative groups with multiple generators, the picture becomes a little more tricky, but there's no time like the present to learn about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group

Comment: @spectraa Here's another example: take the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$.  This is generated by two elements, $a$ and $b$, satisfying $a^2 = 2$ and $b^2 = 3$.  If I want to know if I can make a homomorphism by sending $a$ and $b$ somewhere in some other ring, it's the same situation as what you mention: I just need to check that the images of $a$ and $b$ obey the correct relations in the target.

Comment: @spectraa Oh, and keep in mind that rings can have "relations" that involve no generators.  For example, $1+1=0$ is a relation that may hold.  Only constants are involved, no symbols.  But it's still an important relation that you have to pay attention to when dealing with homomorphisms—you can't have a ring with $1+1=0$ map homomorphically to another ring with $1+1\neq 0$. (all my rings have $1$ here, by the way—the situation is similar for rings without $1$, but a little more annoying to describe)

Comment: @Slade really thanks,This was exactly what I wanted but I can't be in haste to accept your answer as I've to study free groups and then understand it.but your comments seem helpful..

Comment: @spectraa: It is in general a good idea to wait a little while before accepting an answer (also, you should not accept an answer if you do not feel that it answers your question), as accepting too early discourages people from adding an answer

Comment: @Slade: Do you really think the situation is similar for rings without $1$? How would you describe a presentation without a free object?

Comment: @zcn Isn't the initial object just $X\mathbb{Z}[X]$?

Comment: @Slade: Yes, that works (although strictly speaking there are many maps $X\mathbb{Z}[X] \to R$, not a unique one). I guess one should take $(X_i) \mathbb{Z} \langle X_i \rangle$ (the noncommutative polynomials with no constant term) as a free object (incidentally, I have never seen that notation before)

Comment: @zcn I think that's the right general free object.  I just made the notation up—I can't recall seeing a decent notation for this, well, rng.  I almost want to write $[X]$ for the non-unital polynomial ring in one variable. It's definitely not an object I'm very accustomed to thinking about.

Comment: @zcn Oh, you're right.  I confused myself; the initial object should be free on zero generators, not one.  So it's $0$ for non-unital rings and $\mathbb{Z}$ for unital rings.  $X\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is the free object on one generator.

Comment: @Slade: I must say I like both your notations $X\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $[X]$ - they are quite suggestive (I am also rather unaccustomed to thinking about rngs). I agree that $0$ should be initial in rngs

Comment: @zcn Of course, I can't resist the urge to describe $[X]$ as a $\ $-algebra.  And maybe we should deal with zero-divisors in the rng $A$ by passing to the quotient feld, and working with the $Q(\ )$-algebra $A\otimes_{}\ Q(\ )$.

Comment: @Slade it'll be so kind of you if you can clarify these two things to me:  $1.)$As you said  rings can have "relations" that involve no generators.Can you help clarifying it to me with help of example in which there is such a case.. $2.$ I'm preparing for my ring theory exam which consists of ring homomorphism portion and just don't have any time to study what free groups are(I'll do this later on...) can you in a very simple language explain it to me the facts to be considered while writing a presentation of ring homomorphism,so that I can  proceed with my preparation....

Comment: @spectraa 1) I gave an example: in a ring with unity, we can have the relation $1+1=0$, in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for instance.  But $1$ and $0$ are in every ring, so we shouldn't really call them "generators".  2) It's up to you to provide a rigorous definition of what a group presentation _is_, that can be adequately worked with mathematically.  I've been thinking about this subject for a long time, and I don't see how you can begin speaking about these things rigorously without free groups or an equivalent concept.

Comment: @spectraa I was thinking about this today, and I thought of a statement that might help: a free group is just a group with a presentation that has _no relations_.  So if you have a rigorous definition of a group presentation, then you already know what a free group is.  In my experience, however, group presentations are often not defined rigorously, which makes it very difficult to prove things about them.

Answer (score 1):

To check that a map $\phi: G \to H$ between groups is a **(group) homomorphism**, it's enough to verify that $\phi$ respects the product:
$$\phi(g_1 g_2) = \phi(g_1) \phi(g_2) \text{ for all } g_1, g_2 \in G.$$

(Note that your example $\phi : g \mapsto g^2$ is in general not a group homomorphism $G \to G$, but it will be for certain groups.)

Now, rings have $2$ operations, which I'll denote by $+$ and juxtaposition, and ring homomorphisms $R \to S$ must respect both, and (for unital rings) it must map the multiplicative identity of $R$ to that of $S$. (If it satisfies these conditions, it automatically sends $0_R$ to $0_S$, and the same happens for the group homomorphism condition above.)

1. $\phi(1_R) = 1_S$,
2. $\phi(r_1 + r_2) = \phi(r_1) + \phi(r_2)$, and
3. $\phi(r_1 r_2) = \phi(r_1) \phi(r_2)$.

A basic but important example of a ring homomorphism is the map $$\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$$ that reduces modulo $n$, i.e., the map that sends $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the equivalence class $[a] \in \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$. It's perhaps easy but instructive to check the above conditions (1)-(3) to show that this is a (ring) homomorphism. This generalizes to an important class of ring homomorphisms: Given any ring $R$ and ideal $I$, we can form the *quotient ring* $R / I$, and the map $R \to R / I$ that sends an element to its equivalence class in $R / I$ is always a ring homomorphism. In fact, the kernel of *any* ring homomorphism is an ideal, so all ideals arise this way.

Comment: I understand that for being a ring homomorphism all these 3 conditions need to be satisfied.But my doubt is that to check these conditions are satisfied by all elements of ring will become tiresome.so we need to switch to relations as in case of groups in my example .What relations need to be satisfied in rings...

Comment: In practice, you don't have to check the conditions for all elements of a ring manually, you simply use the abstract properties of the ring elements.

Comment: Note that depending on your choice of definition of rings, not all rings have unit elements.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I'll modify the answer to emphasize that this is for unital rings.