# Showing that a map from $S_3$ to $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is homomorphism

Tags: permutations, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

The following is from *Representation Theory of Finite Groups*, by B. Steinberg; Example 3.1.14, p.16:

> Let $\rho:S_3\to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ be specified on the generators $(1
>  \ 2)$ and $(1 \ 2\ 3)$ by
>
> $$\rho_{(1 \ 2)}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \
>  \rho_{(1 \ 2 \ 3)}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

I'm trying to verify that  $\rho:S_3\to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is a representation. By definition a representation is homomorphism, thus I want to show that $\rho_{gh}=\rho_g\rho_h$ for every $g,h\in S_3$. Starting with 
$$\rho_{(1 \ 2)}\rho_{(1 \ 2 \ 3)}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
we need to verify that $\rho_{(1 \ 2)(1 \ 2 \ 3)}=\rho_{(2 \ 3)}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, but I can't see how to do that. Moreover, I have doubts on checking the homomorphism property only for generators, that is, why checking the homomorphism property for the generators is enough to establish that $\rho$ is a representation?

Comment: You are supposed to define $\rho_{(23)}$ to be that.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402612) .

So, a presentation for $S_3$ is $\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^3=(ab)^2=1\rangle$.

Take $a=(12)$ and $b=(123)$.

You just need to check that $\rho (r_i)=1$ for each of the relations.

Once you establish that $\rho$ is a homomorphism,  you will have that it's a representation of $S_3$ on $\mathbb C^2$ by definition.

Comment: Of course, you need to still show it's a homomorphism. Defining it on generators is not enough.

Comment: Right you are...  I was trying to correct it when I noticed your comment.