# Finding all group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have tried to come up with a way, so I was wondering if it is correct, and if there are any other ways which work in this (or other) cases? Thanks.

Let $G = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$

Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3 \to \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$. The order of the image of $\phi$ must divide $6$ and $8$, so it can only be $1$ or $2$. If the order is $1$, then  $\phi$ must be the trivial homomorphism.

If the order of the image is $2$, then the order of the kernel is $4$, and the image must be $\{\overline{0}, \overline{4} \}.$ So all we have to do is find all subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ which have order $4$ (they will automatically be normal). Then, if $H$ is such a subgroup, we define $\phi$ to be $\overline{0}$ for all elements of that subgroup, it must be the case that $\phi$ to be $\overline{4}$ for all the other elements.

To see that any such map is a homomorphism, consider the following: Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $4$, and $\phi$ be the homomorphism constructed above. Then there is the natural projection homomorphism $\pi: G\to G/H.$ But $ H\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong \{\overline{0}, \overline{4} \}$ (in $\mathbb{Z} / 8 \mathbb{Z}$), so any map of the type discussed above is a homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3 \to \mathbb{Z}/8 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: A homomorphism is uniquely defined by where it sends a generating set. Choose a nice generating set of $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^3, and see where each of them can possibly be sent.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, I will try that! Is my approach of finding every subgroup of order $4$, sending that to $\overline {0}$, and sending its coset to $\overline {3}$, also correct?

Comment: Replace all of your $3$s by $4$s. The image of any element must have order $1$ or $2$, and $4$ is the only element of order $2$ in the target space.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Oh right, I was thinking of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. So that approach is correct then?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but what Arthur suggests it somewhat easier.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Ah okay. So a nice generating set is $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) \}$. Each member has order $2$, so each must be sent either to $\overline{0}$ or $\overline {4 }$. But there are $8$ such maps. How do I know which one gives a homomorphism and which one doesn't? Do I just check $\phi(ab)  = \phi(a) \phi(b)$ for all possible $a, b$ for each map?

Comment: @Arthur Please see my comment above.

Comment: All of them do. In fact there are $8$ ways to choose who goes where, and each of these can be extended into a homomorphism. If you've made sure that each generator is mapped to an element of consistent order, then it always extends into a map.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I guess it kind of makes sense, but since I have to prove it, is there another way other than going through all of those computations?

Comment: You can read Lee Mosher's answer here for a proof of what I just said: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1402612

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks!