# Question about the definition of tensor product of homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I am working on an exercise about tensor products. We introduced them as the **quotient space** given by the following definition:

> For two Abelian groups $A$ and $B$ we define their tensor product
> $A\otimes B$ as the quotient of the free Abelian group on the set of
> formal generators $\{a \otimes b \mid a \in A; b \in B\}$ by the
> subgroup generated by elements of the form $$a_1 \otimes b + a_2
>  \otimes b − (a_1 + a_2) \otimes b$$ and $$a\otimes b_1 +a\otimes b_2
>  −a\otimes(b_1 +b_2).$$ By abuse of notation we write $a\otimes b$ for
> the corresponding element in the quotient $A \otimes B.$

Now what i am working on is:

> Two homomorphisms $f\colon A\to A'$ and $g\colon B\to B'$ induce a homomorphism $$f\otimes b\colon A\otimes B \to A'\otimes B'\ \ \text{with}\ \ f\otimes g(a\otimes b) = f(a)\otimes g(b)$$

So the proposed solution says that the prescription of this map is a well defined homomorphism from the set of formal generators $\{a \otimes b \mid a \in A; b \in B\}$ to the quotient $A'\otimes B'$.

However, i can't see why this is supposed to be the case.

In order to verify $f\otimes g$ is a (well defined) homomorphism i need to show that

$$f\otimes g\colon \{a \otimes b \mid a \in A; b \in B\}\to A'\otimes B',\ (a\otimes b)+(a'\otimes b') \mapsto [f(a)\otimes g(b)]+[f(a')\otimes g(b')]$$
where $[\cdot]$ denotes an equivalence class in the quotient $A'\otimes B'$.

Now what i've tried is to work out whether the map between the set of formal generators

$$\widetilde{f\otimes g}\colon \{a \otimes b \mid a \in A; b \in B\}\to \{f(a) \otimes f(b) \mid f(a) \in A'; g(b) \in B'\}$$

is a homomorphism, because that would imply that the composition $f\otimes g = p\circ\widetilde{f\otimes g}$ with the projection map $p$ would be a homomorphism and i would be done (after checking well-definedness).

But the issue i am having is that i do not know how to prove that $\widetilde{f\otimes g}$ itself is a homomorphism, given the definition above.

**Please note**: I would like to solve this without any usage of the universal property and bilinear-maps. Is it possible to solve it just by the definition via the quotient from above?

Comment: In nyour definition of the ten,sor product of homomorphisms, I think it should be $f\otimes g$ everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does $f\otimes g$ send your relation
$$a_1\otimes b+a_2\otimes b-(a_1+a_2)\otimes b?$$
It sends it to
$$f(a_1)\otimes g(b)+f(a_2)\otimes g(b)-f(a_1+a_2)\otimes g(b)$$
which equals
$$f(a_1)\otimes g(b)+f(a_2)\otimes g(b)-(f(a_1)+f(a_2))\otimes g(b)$$
and that is precisely one of the relations in $A'\otimes B'$.

The same works for all relations of the second type. Since the map
$a\otimes b\mapsto f(a)\otimes g(b)$ sends relations to relations,
it induces a map $A\otimes B\to A'\otimes B'$.

Comment: Hi @Angina Seng, thank you very much for your answer. Regarding your last paragraph, the technical details are they the same covered by Lee Mosher's answer here? 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1402612

Comment: Or to put it differently: Would you mind explaining your last paragraph regarding the induced map? Does that simply follow from the homomorphism theorem?

Comment: Let's say you have a homomorphism of Abelian groups $\phi:G\to H$ and subgroups $G_1$ and $H_1$ of $G$ and $H$. Then $\phi$ induces a homomorphism $G/G_1\to H/H_1$ sending the coset $a+G_1$ to $\phi(a)+H_1$ as long as $\phi(G_1)\subseteq H_1$. To check that, all you need is $\phi(a)\in H_1$ where $a$ runs through a set of generators for $G_1$.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But my issue here is that we already assume that $\phi\colon G\to H$ is a homomorphism, but i was struggling to prove that my map from the set of formal generators $\{a\otimes b\}$ to the set of formal generators $\{f(a)\otimes f(b)\}$ is a homomorphism in the first place.

Comment: Recall we are first considering the **free** Abelian group generated by the $a\otimes b$.