# Is there a foolproof method to calculate the inverse of a group homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

For example, take the group $\langle a,b\mid a^{-1}b^2ab^{-3}\rangle$, and the homomorphism given induced by the map $a \rightarrow a$, $b \rightarrow b^2$. Is there a method that will  let you calculate the inverse of a homomorphism of a finitely presented group?

Comment: Do you mean the inverse of an "isomorphism" ?

Comment: Yes indeed, I only want to calculate the inverse in cases when it exists. So I suppose it would be useful to know the quickest method to check if we're working with an isomorphism or homomorphism as well

Comment: Your example is not an isomorphism so it has no inverse. This is a standard example of a non-Hopfian group, due to Baumslag and Solitar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's a simple brute-force algorithm that always works.  Let us suppose $f:\langle A\mid R\rangle\to\langle B\mid S\rangle$ is an isomorphism and we have an expression for $f(a)$ as a word in elements of $B$ for each $a\in A$.  To find the inverse, take every single word $w$ in $A$ and attempt to use the relations in $S$ to reduce $f(w)$ to some element of $B$.  Dovetailing these computations over all words $w$, you will eventually find for each $b\in B$ some $w_b$ such that $f(w_b)=b$.  Then, the inverse is given by $f(b)=w_b$.

Note that there is not any algorithm that determines *whether* a homomorphism between two finitely presented groups is an isomorphism.  Indeed, there is no algorithm that determines whether a finitely presented group is trivial, and so in particular there is no algorithm that determines whether the trivial homomorphism between two finitely presented groups is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

A group is *Hopfian* if every surjective homomorphism is an isomorphism (that is, surjective implies injective). This property was discussed at length in [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79852/10513).

Your map is not injective, and hence has no inverse. As Derek Holt points out in the comments, this is *the* standard example of a finitely presented non-Hopfian group.

The Baumslag-Solitar group $\operatorname{BS}(2, 3)=\langle a, b\mid a^{-1}b^2ab^{-3}\rangle$ is not Hopfian. To see this, consider the map you give in your question, $\phi: a\mapsto a$, $b\mapsto b^2$. Then $\phi(ba^{-1}bab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a)=1$ (this is easy to see) but $ba^{-1}bab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a\neq1$ (this is harder to see - it follows from [Britton's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension#Britton's_Lemma) for HNN-extensions).